# Functions and their Distinct Variants

Tags: permutations

Here's a question I've been working on:

> For which of the values of $n$ and $k$ does there exist a function of $n$ variables that has $k$ distinct variants?

For example, when $n = 2$ and $k = 1$, I claim that there **does exist a function** and I chose the function $x_1x_2$. It has two variables $(n = 2)$ and if we write down all the possible variants, we have $x_1x_2$ and $x_2x_1$, but these two are equivalent (commutative property of multiplication). In other words, $k = 1$.
But, how about when $n$ is arbitrary and $n = k$? I'm not sure if this statement holds true or not.

Comment: Your definition of $k$ is a little strange.  There are two versions of your function $x_1x_2$ and $x_2x_1$ so it would be more normal to define $k=2$ in your example.  In your final question, your example would be a case of $n=k$ if you didn't subtract $1$ from $k$.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Ah yes I have several typos. I will revise right now.

Comment: I'm not sure if the edit helped out or not, but feel free to ask anything.

Comment: I don't think it helped.  My point is that it seems more natural to say $k=2$ for this function as there are two permutations of the variables.  That makes is much easier to cast the evaluation of $k$ in terms of multinomial coefficients.  For example, if we use my $k$, for $n=k=3$ we can have the function $x_1x_1x_2$ which has three permutations.  For your $k$ we would demand four permutations, the original one plus three.

Comment: Ahh okay I see how your looking at it then. Is it possible to show the result of the latter question I posted if we use your perspective of interpreting $k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we redefine $k$ as the number of equivalent functions with total degree $n$ there is always a function with $n=k$.  We can just use $x_1^{n-1}x_2$.  The $x_2$ can go in any position in the string, so there are $n$ different functions.

If you insist on $n$ different variables, there are $n!$ permutations of them.  Your example with two variables and two orders works because $2=2!$.  The only other case of that is $1!=1$, so for $n=k=1$ there is a solution $x_1$, which has only one function.

Comment: This does make sense. So is the top portion is basically how *you* would approach the question (based on how you evaluate $k$ and $n$) correct? The second half of your explanation is clear.

Comment: It is correct if $n$ is total degree instead of the number of distinct variables.  It comes from the mutinomial coefficient.  You start with $n$ different variables, which gives $n!$ distinct functions.  If you make $m$ of the variables the same, you divide the number of functions by $m!$.  Since $\frac {n!}{(n-1)!}=n$ by identifying all  the variables except one I get $n$ equivalent functions.

Comment: That's really interesting. It never occurred to even consider your perspective of the problem. But yes, this explanation clears it up.